# C programming Percentage help 2 dice programn Rolled 10000 times

Tags: c

Starting from scratch, repeat Part 4, with 2 dice.   Let’s use 10,000 this time instead of 1000.

Each die can be from 1 - 6, so the total of 2 dice must be in the range 2 – 12.

Your output will be in the range of 2 – 12.

Notice that it is much less likely to roll a 2 than it is to roll a 7, since a 2 can only be rolled a  1 + 1.  But a 7 can be 6 + 1, 5 + 2, 4 + 3, 3 + 4, 2 + 5, 1 + 6.

Count how many times each value occurs and output that count as in the previous part.

Calculate what percentage of the time you roll a 2, 3, 4, etc. up to 12.  Output the percentages with an accuracy of one place past the decimal.  Post the results of this one on the discussion board.

My question is in my program I wrote it so that it outputs the amount rolled. I'm having extreme problems trying to use a percentage formula to output the % of the rolled dice.

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 11
#define TOTAL 10000


int main(void)   {

    int cnt = 0;
    int die1, die2, sum;
    int array[SIZE];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; cnt++)
        array[cnt] = 0;

    for (cnt = 0; cnt < TOTAL; cnt++)
    {
        die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        sum = die1 + die2;
        ++array[sum-2];
    }
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; cnt++)
        printf("Number of %d's: %d\n", cnt+2, array[cnt]);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), so please don't use it.

Comment: What exactly have you tried for the percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
array[cnt]*100/SIZE;
```

Also

you may wish to look this up [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: Which line should I put that code in? should I change the %d into %.2lf?

Comment: Perhaps this line `printf("Number of %d's: %d\n", cnt+2, array[cnt]);
` but then again it is YOUR homework

Comment: Thank you for the help. I figured it out. 

printf("Number of %d's: %.1lf\n", cnt+2, (float)array[cnt]*100/TOTAL)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you stored your "counts" for a single die in an array, perhaps you might have something like:

> array[0] is the #/times I rolled a "1" for a single die; array[1] the #/times I rolled a "2", etc.

Perhaps for *two dice*, you want the array to store the *sums*.  For example:

> array[0] is the #/times I rolled a sum of "2" for both dice; array[1] the #/times I rolled "3", etc.

How big should the array be?  You'll never have a sum less than 2, or greater than 12.  So "int[SIZE]" ("11") should suffice.

And you'll need to clear all the elements in the array to "0" before you start rolling.

'Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction...